# Message Queue MSMQ always defaults to workgroup instead of domain mode on SBS 2008

Tags: .net

I don't know too much about MSMQ. I need to install it on a client's machine. It is a small business server 2008.

I installed MSMQ (including the messaging queue and Directory Service Integration) However, it always defaults back to workgroup mode instead of domain mode for some reason, i tried so many different things, still didn't work :(

I am on a SBS 2008, so the domain is actually local domain. Domain is something like SysServer.local

I am wondering would that cause any problems? Any gurus out there that could help?

Comment: just in case, might also be worth asking at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I'm not a guru but I know windows server and msmq, I'll see if I can find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is atleast 2 common problems causing this.

- From the server manager, when you
  install the msmq feature, **it says it
  will install the directory subfeature
  as well but it doesn't**(according to
  [this](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/installing-msmq-domain-mode-windows-server-2008)).

  Can you check again to make sure the
  directory subfeature of msmq was
  installed, you might need to install
  the directory feature again, manually.
  btw, you can also check this from
  command line:

  servermanagercmd -q

  the stuff in green is the stuff
  installed
- Also, **msmq may not work after a
  computer has been [renamed](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/installing-msmq-domain-mode-windows-server-2008)**, you
  could use ADSI Edit, and drill down to the
  the msmqConfiguration node, check that
  it's using the current GUID of your server, not the old one.

  [1](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/installing-msmq-domain-mode-windows-server-2008): [1](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/installing-msmq-domain-mode-windows-server-2008):    http://kbalertz.com/284851/Message-Queuing-Allow-Rejoin-Domain-After-Rename-Computer.aspx